# Java DSL for dynamic logic

Tags: java, dsl, java-11

We have Groovy DSL using which we could store the logic to be executed in DB and execute the same groovy script in Java.

Is is possible with Java also?  I am using Java 11.

The requirement is to read JSON input and update the value for the given field. The field and the logic should be dynamic.

Comment: Did you mean without using a library? Or a [3rd party library](http://camel.apache.org/java-dsl.html) works? Note - This is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I prefer without a library. The requirement is to have N number of logic to be executed.

Answer (score 4):

The question seems to be too "broad" and theoretical to some extent

If I understand it correctly, you're asking whether its possible to create a DSL in Java...

If so, the answer is Yes.
Whether it will have the same level of expressiveness as you can have in Groovy? No...

Java from the language syntax standpoint is a pretty outdated language, that's basically a first reason why have "newer" languages like Scala Groovy and recently Kotlin have emerged on top of JVM.

Having syntactical constructions for writing concise and expressive DSLs is something that Java offers in a very limited manner whereas more modern languages have more constructions up their sleeves.

That's possibly the reason why maintainers of DSL usually chose Groovy / Kotlin as a DSL language and not Java.
Examples:

- Gradle - which is basically a groovy based DSL for building the project (recently it got a kotlin support too)
- Jenkins pipelines - a Groovy DSL for running CI on the projects

Having said that, it's not true that there its totally impossible to build DSLs with Java only with APIs.

Here are the examples:

Mockito has a DSL for specifying expectations for tests. Example:

```
when(foo.bar(a,b,c)).thenReturn(d);
```

Another example of a (fairly successful IMO) attempt to create a DSL  is [JOOQ](https://www.jooq.org/)
This library provides a very nice DSL for working with Relational Databases.

Here is an example of how does the DSL built with Jooq looks like (Java, not Groovy):

```
jooqContext
    .select()
    .from(MY_TABLE)
    .fetch()
```

So, you can borrow ideas of how DSLs can look like in these languages compare and decide for yourself.